# Custom Marker using Google Maps Android API Utility Library

Tags: android, google-maps, markerclusterer

I'm using Google Maps Android API Utility Library in order to show several markers in a map in a clustered way. I can't find a way to change default red marker to custom marker

Does anybody have any idea about this[image]?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Check this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering

Comment: Roman Zhukov , I checked the official link but they did't mention anything about to change default red icon to custom. Only Customize the marker of clusters

Comment: how did you change, kindly post code me also struggling with same issue

Answer (score 2):

In order to change the marker you need to override the `onClusterItemRendered` method of your custom renderer.

Then change it like this:

```
  @Override
    protected void onClusterItemRendered(ListingCluster clusterItem, final Marker marker) {
        super.onClusterItemRendered(clusterItem, marker);
        try {
            marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_marker_detail));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean my code? This is how you should do it. If you know how this library works then you will have no problem implementing what I just said. You haven't posted any code yourself so...

Comment: Actually the thing is that i have more then one marker drawable and i want to make the cluster of different Shape marker like my first marker drawable is R.drawable.map_marker_detail,R.drawable.map_marker_detail1,R.drawable.map_marker_detail3 like t

Comment: Just put type of object into your class inherited from ClusterItem and check that type in onClusterItemRendered.